# Using firebase cloud functions vs. GCP Cloud functions for a firestore trigger

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm building an application in React that uses Firebase Auth and Firestore. I'm now at a point where I need to start processing payments with stripe. I would like to do this with cloud functions and Firestore. Here comes my question and where I would like some advice.

I have experience with Google Cloud Platform cloud functions but have none with firebase cloud functions.

I was looking at learning Firebase cloud functions - however I just saw that GCP functions also support a Firestore trigger (in BETA version). I have seen similar threads that ask whether this is possible and I know it is but I just want to know what the downsides are of just using GCP cloud functions instead of firebase cloud functions?

Answer (score 4):

They are fundamentally the same product, and have the same performance and functional capabilities.  Firebase just adds SDKs and APIs on top of Google Cloud Functions that make it easier to work with for mobile app developers.  You choose which set of tools you prefer.  That's going to be a matter of experimentation and research to figure out what's best for your situation.  Many people prefer Firebase tools because they give you a strongly typed API description of the documents that were changed, but it does not really add any additional capability to the core Cloud Functions product.

If you want to read more about the relationship between Firebase and Google Cloud on the topic of Cloud Functions, [read this post](https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-functions-612d9e1e89cb).

Comment: Also, be sure to check out Stripe's Firebase extensions. They're built and maintained by Stripe, and depending on what you're after could be a great fit! https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-stripe-subscriptions